# How to find difference of two row values and store it as third row in the same table?

Tags: sql-server

I want to find difference between two rows of a table and insert the difference value as third row in the same table. If the first row value is less than second row then the difference should appear within parenthesis instead of negative symbol.

Ex:

```
Name        S1   S2   S3   S4

xxx         98   70   50   85    
xxx1        50   90   35  105    
Diff        48  (20)  15  (20)
```

Kindly say whether is it possible either in front-end, that is after storing the values in gridview. But in Gridview the colums and rows are Transposed. Then in grid view difference of two column store as third new column.

Comment: and where's your attempt? Also, presentation is not a concern of storage. They're separate. You'd be wise to keep them as such.

Comment: Adding to what Mitch says. Consider creating a view in the DB with that result rather than adding the data.  Depending on your situation.

Comment: You can do what you are looking for, but will most likely have to join the data to its self with an off-set to link xxx and xxx1.  How do these records relate to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code which will do it:

```
SELECT
     Name
    ,S1
    ,S2
FROM 
(
    select
         x.Name as xName
        ,CONVERT(varchar(99), x.S1) as xS1      -- Have to convert everything since you require negatives as ()
        ,CONVERT(varchar(99), x.S2) as xS2
        ,1 as xOrder                            -- To ensure the rows are presented as requested

        ,x1.Name as x1Name
        ,CONVERT(varchar(99), x1.S1) as x1S1
        ,CONVERT(varchar(99), x1.S2) as x1S2
        ,2 as x1Order

        ,case 
            when SIGN(x.S1 - x1.S1) = -1 
                then '(' + CONVERT(varchar(99), x.S1 - x1.S1) + ')'
            else CONVERT(varchar(99), x.S1 - x1.S1)
        end as d1
        ,case 
            when SIGN(x.S2 - x1.S2) = -1 
                then '(' + CONVERT(varchar(99), x.S2 - x1.S2) + ')'
            else CONVERT(varchar(99), x.S2 - x1.S2)
        end as d2
        -- etc for S3 and S4
        ,3 as DiffOrder
    from
        (select * from dbo.Data where Name = 'xxx') as x
    inner join
        (select * from dbo.Data where Name = 'xxx1') as x1
        on x1.Name = x.Name + '1'   -- I suspect your row matching conditin will have 
                                    -- to me more sophisticated that this in realit
) as Data
-- The cross apply does an UNPIVOT on the cheap
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES
                (xName, xS1, xS2, xOrder),
                (x1Name, x1S1, x1S2, x1Order),
                ('Diff', d1, d2, DiffOrder)
            ) -- Close paren from the CROSS APPLY
            as ca(Name, S1, S2, SortOrder)
order by ca.SortOrder;
```

It would be much, much better to have your presentation layer perform the formatting of negatives.

Because you require negatives presented in this way the columns have to be `CONVERTed` to character types.  This adds complexity to the SQL.  It may also mean they are no longer right-aligned.  Again, good presentation software should be able to deal with that for you better than SQL can.

I suspect that in your actual system you will have many row-pairs.  You haven't said what the rules to match them are.  You will have to add this into the code.  Make sure you change the sorting to account for this also.

The code could be reformatted using CTEs, if you find that layout simpler to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you intend to insert varchar into a numeric column. I assume s1-s4 are numeric as they should be.

You have your data reversed, so best thing is to spin it 90 degrees first to do the calculation, then after the result turn it back to display it correct:

```
declare @t table(Name varchar(4), S1 int, S2 int, S3 int, S4 int)

insert @t values('xxx',98,70,50,85),
('xxx1',50,90,35,105)
--Diff        48  (20)  15  (20)

-- this next part can be put into a view

;with cte as
(
select 
sum(case when Name = 'xxx' then Value else -value end) Total, Col 
from @t t1
UNPIVOT      
(Value FOR Col IN           
([S1], [S2], [S3], [S4]) ) AS unpvt  
group by col
), cte2 as
(
select case when Total < 0 then 
'(' + cast(-Total as varchar(10))+')'
else cast(Total as varchar(10)) end Totalvarchar, Col
from cte
)
select Name, 
cast(S1 as varchar(20)) S1, cast(S2 as varchar(20)) S2, 
cast(S3 as varchar(20)) S3, cast(S4 as varchar(20)) S4
from @t
union all
select 'Diff' Name, [S1], [S2], [S3], [S4]
from
cte2
PIVOT (max(TotalVarchar) FOR [Col] IN ([S1], [S2], [S3], [S4])) AS pvt
```

Result:

```
Name   S1   S2   S3   S4
xxx    98   70   50   85
xxx1   50   90   35  105
Diff   48 (20)   15 (20)
```